# Problema con los array y los punteros

Tags: c

Tengo el problema que la función no edita correctamente el array, y no comprendo el porque pasa. Le tengo que pasar un array por parte de puntero y con la misma función editar los valores del puntero y los siguientes.

```
void foo(double *p) {
    *p = 2;
    *(p+1)=3;
    *(p+2)=4;
}
```

Comment: You are on the spanish version of [so], so please translate it or move it to the right site. / Estás en [es.so], por lo que las preguntas tienen que estar en español, así que considera traducirla o pedir que se mueva al sitio correcto.

Comment: Debes dar más detalles del error ¿a qué te refieres con que "no edita correctament el array"? ¿Rompe la ejecución? ¿Sale algo diferente de lo que esperabas? ¿Qué esperabas y qué sale? Por otro lado ¿qué array? En el código que muestras sólo se ve un puntero y ningún array. Sin ver desde dónde llamas a la función y qué parámetro le pasas poco se puede hacer.

Answer (score 0):

al momento de llamar a tu funcion supongo que lo estas haciendo de la
siguiente manera no?

```
int main(){
double *p_principal;
//demas codigo
   foo (&p_principal);

}

void foo(double *p) {
    *p = 2;
    *(p+1)=3;
    *(p+2)=4;
}
```

Comment: ¡Espero que no! Sería incorrecto a muchos niveles

Comment: El código en ese caso no debería compilar. Estas pasando un `double**` en lugar de un `double*`.